# streamwrite override more than just "Write" function

Tags: c#, console, overriding

This is my current code for my textwriter class:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleRedirection
{
    public class TextBoxStreamWriter : TextWriter
    {
        TextBox _output = null;

        public TextBoxStreamWriter(TextBox output)
        {
            _output = output;
        }

        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            base.Write(value);
            _output.AppendText(value.ToString());

        }
        public override void Write(string value)
        {
            _output.AppendText(value);
        }
        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it does fine to override the Write functions, but I want to be able to override everything from Clear to color setting. I tried adding a Clear override, but it said there was nothing to override.

How can I override all the functions I need to in System.Console?

Answer (score 0):

Simply because TextWriter doesn't contains clear or color setting function.
Check [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter(v=vs.110).aspx).
Try to create a new method without overriding like:

```
public void Clear()
{
    _output.Clear();
}
```

Comment: when I tried that with a Console.Clear, it threw me an error.

Comment: because your are using winform, and in winform you cannot clear console ( As i know ).

Comment: well in all honesty, console.clear() is an actual command, however what I ended up trying after your solution was to set the textbox text to "", which still didn't work.

Comment: use there is a console.clear() and if you using directly from form it'll throw an io error just like the error your are facing cuz it's already using by other wrtier.  
so actualy you cannot using console.clear().

Comment: that's why I'm trying to override it. The same way Console.Write gets handled by the text writer class, I want the Console.Clear function to follow suit.

Comment: Ran into a similar problem. Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to edit the textbox content try this code

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleRedirection
{
    public class TextBoxStreamWriter
    {
        TextBox _output = null;

        public TextBoxStreamWriter(ref TextBox output)
        {
            _output = output;
        }

        public void Write(char value)
        {
            _output.AppendText(value.ToString());
        }
        public void Write(string value)
        {
            _output.AppendText(value);
        }
        public Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
        }

        public void clear()
        {
            _output.Clear();
        }

        public void textColor(System.Drawing.Color color)
        {
            _output.ForeColor = color;
        }
    }
}
```

and to creating a new instance of your class

```
ConsoleRedirection.TextBoxStreamWriter tbxw = new ConsoleRedirection.TextBoxStreamWriter(ref textbox1);
```

Comment: again, that doesn't work. It throws:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.

Comment: i don't why you get this error, i try this code and work like charm.

Comment: try to download this and see if it's work  
you'll need vs2015.  
[google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZASK21ZjGOMzVaeENEX1kxTkE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: yes but the method you used is different. I used 
_writer = new TextBoxStreamWriter(txtConsole);
Console.SetOut(_writer);
Console.WriteLine("\nNow redirecting output to the text box");